# How to acquire the "mm semaphore" in C?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

If you want to use the `remap_pfn_range` function within a custom kernel driver implementing mmap, you know that you have to acquire the 'mm semaphore'. But it's not clear how to do so from the examples that I can find publicly available. I think it would benefit the community to edit the examples that are available, and I'm willing to do so, but I don't know where to start.

As per the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-remap-pfn-range.html): *this is only safe if the mm semaphore is held when called.*

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63528950/is-mmap-callback-called-with-mmap-sem-held

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It helps to look at the actual source [for `remap_pfn_range`].  That's in the `mm` subdirectory, specifically in `mm/memory.c`

There you'll see `struct mm_struct *mm = vma->vm_mm;` so that's the `mm` you want.  Note that is also [probably] `current->mm`

If you look around in a few more files there [notably `mm/mmap.c`], you'll see `down_write(&mm->mmap_sem)` and `up_write(&mm->mmap_sem)` [which are the kernel's semaphore primitives].  Note that if you only needed to read from the area, there are `down_read` and `up_read`

So, to put it all together:

```
void
myfnc(...)
{
    struct vm_area_struct *vma = ...;
    struct mm_struct *mm = vma->vm_mm;

    ...

    down_write(&mm->mmap_sem);
    remap_pfn_range(vma,...);
    up_write(&mm->mmap_sem);

    ...
}
```

Documentation aside, one of the best ways to find these things is the look through the source itself.  I've been writing linux kernel/driver code for 20+ years and it's what I do when I need to find something that I don't know about.

Comment: Thanks! I think that that's it. I didn't know where the actual definition of the function was. I went to lxr and hit up the identifier search, but that brought up a zillion files. Thanks for the tip, and heck, it helps others when they're looking around. Plus, now I can improve the open source examples that are out there! :D

Comment: You're welcome! I'll try update my answer a bit later with some of my tips.  But, here's an easy one.  In the top kernel directory do: `ctags -R` [Note: it has many options]. This will create a file `tags`. Now you can do: `vi -t remap_pfn_range`. Once you have the `tags` file, within `vi` you can do: `:ta remap_pfn_range` [or any symbol]. If vi's `:help ta` doesn't work, do `zless /usr/share/vim/vim74/doc/tagsrch.txt.gz`. Although I've not used it myself, `cscope` may also be useful

Answer (score 3):

First of all i don't really understand a bit of linux :) and i don't why I did the search for you :)

Here is what i found:

1- mm refers to memory map [here](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-1) under the **15.1.7. The Process Memory Map** title:

> The final piece of the memory management puzzle is the process memory map structure, which holds all of the other data structures together. Each process in the system (with the exception of a few kernel-space helper threads) has a struct mm_struct (defined in ) that contains the process's list of virtual memory areas, page tables, and various other bits of memory management housekeeping information, along with a semaphore (mmap_sem) and a spinlock (page_table_lock). The pointer to this structure is found in the task structure; in the rare cases where a driver needs to access it, the usual way is to use current->mm. Note that the memory management structure can be shared between processes; the Linux implementation of threads works in this way, for example.

2- the `mm_struct` is defined as:

```
struct mm_struct {
    int count;
    pgd_t * pgd;
    unsigned long context;
    unsigned long start_code, end_code, start_data, end_data;
    unsigned long start_brk, brk, start_stack, start_mmap;
    unsigned long arg_start, arg_end, env_start, env_end;
    unsigned long rss, total_vm, locked_vm;
    unsigned long def_flags;
    struct vm_area_struct * mmap;
    struct vm_area_struct * mmap_avl;
    struct semaphore mmap_sem; /**this what you are looking for**/
};
```

3- Finally, [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand021.html) there are examples for locking and unlocking (down_write and up_write) the mmap_sem attribute.

I have to confess again, i really don't understand what's going on :) Somehow i wanted to find a solution.

Hope it helps,
Gokhan.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Craig's answer, as of Linux 5.8, the VMA lock is changed to `mmap_lock`. You have to do the following:

```
down_write(&mm->mmap_lock);
remap_pfn_range...
up_write(&mm->mmap_lock);
```

In addition, A new set of API is being developed:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.2/source/include/linux/mmap_lock.h

This VMA lock is a contentious issue in the Linux community:
https://lwn.net/Articles/787629/