# Is mmap callback called with mmap_sem held?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

When we reach the callback of `mmap` of a `struct file_operations` in a Linux kernel module, can we assume that the `vma->vm_mm->mm_sem` is already held before the callback is invoked?
Or do we have to explicitly call `down_write(&vma->vm_mm->mmap_sem)` before doing `remap_pfn_range`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mmap` file operation handler should assume the mmap lock is already write-locked when it is called.  The `mmap` file handler is called via `call_mmap()` via `mmap_region()` via `do_mmap()`, and the following comment appears before the `do_mmap()` function in "mm/mmap.c":

```
/*
 * The caller must write-lock current->mm->mmap_lock.
 */
```

N.B. The mmap lock was renamed from `mmap_sem` to `mmap_lock` in Linux kernel 5.8. The corresponding comment in the 5.7 kernel is:

```
/*
 * The caller must hold down_write(&current->mm->mmap_sem).
 */
```

`do_mmap()` is called via `do_mmap_pgoff()` (in "include/linux/mm.h") via `vm_mmap_pgoff()` (in "mm/util.c") via `ksys_mmap_pgoff()` (in "mm/mmap.c") via the `mmap_pgoff()` syscall handler (in "mm/mmap.c"). (N.B. From kernel version 5.9 onwards, [`do_mmap_pgoff()` is eliminated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=45e55300f11495ed58c53427da7f0d958800a30f) and `do_mmap()` is called directly from `vm_mmap_pgoff()`.) The mmap lock is write-locked in `vm_mmap_pgoff()`.

Comment: And we hold the lock at the `vm_mmap_pgoff` function.

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20.7/source/mm/util.c#L348

Comment: @soham Good point. I'll mention that in the answer.